# Is JSR 311 mandatory for creating RESTful type of Web service?

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I know that RESTful service is more about creating an architecture. Considering this statement i've extended my plain java class with `HTTPServlet` and have used `doGet`&`doPost` method as my web methods and everything seems working fine. I have tested this service by sending requests and it is also responding with a status line. Now what i am getting confused at, is this really a RESTful web service. And if yes, then what is `jsr311` api for ? Isn't it mandatory to use `jsr311` api/jar for creating Rest web service ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JAX-RS](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/) is is set of APIs and specifications for implementing RESTful services with Java.

There are several implementations of JAX-RS, [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) is the Reference Implementation

The first JSR for JAX-RS was ["JSR 311: JAX-RS: The JavaTM API for RESTful Web Services"](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311). One of the artifacts produced for it is an API implemented by Java Interfaces. This API allows to implemente RESTful services with Java.

The current version of JAX-RS is defined in the ["JSR 339: JAX-RS 2.0: The Java API for RESTful Web Services"](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=339).

Since REST is an architectural style and not a product or a library, you can implement a RESTful HTTP service using plain Servlets. The idea behind JAX-RS is, that using just Servlets is too much work and that it ist usefult to have a standard way to implement a RESTful service using Java. JAX-RS defines this standard.

If you use JAX-RS, then your system will have a dependency on the JAX-RS API library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and deppendencies on the libraries of the JAX-RS implementation you use.

Answer (score 1):

No not at all.

Raw Servlets is a fine for implementing a REST architecture. The assorted frameworks and libraries simply make that task a bit easier.